# How to get Each value from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get each value from Firebase and set it to my variable (Lat&Long)

My Code :

```
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
            reference.child("Hutan").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//                        String Bude = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                        String Lat = snapshot.child("Lat").getValue().toString();
                        String Long = snapshot.child("Long").getValue().toString();
                        LatLng Bude = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(Lat), Double.valueOf(Long));
//                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Bude).title("Curug Dago!"));
//                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Bude, 17));
                        Log.e("TAG", "Location: " + Bude);
                    }

                }
```

and [image: Firebase]

The log result said
[image: LOG CAT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Java, here is the code that can help you read the value of `Lat`, as well the value of `Long`:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hutanRef = db.child("Hutan");
hutanRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            double lat = snapshot.child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
            double lng = snapshot.child("Long").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lat + ", " + lng);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, there is no need for any loop. You can directly access both values. The result in the logcat will be:

```
-6.858573273779082, 107.630600755386
```

P.S. Try to find reasonable field names, as Long in the database might be confused with the Long class. So you can use `latitude` and `longitude`, or even simpler, `lat` and `lng`.